# google cloud build docker context

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I have the following file structure:

```
my_repo
        ├── dataflow
        .         ├── pipelines
        .         │         ├── pipeline1
        .         │         │         ├── Dockerfile
                  │         │         ├── pipeline1_module.py
                  │         │         └── main.py
                  │         └── pipeline2
                  │                   ├── Dockerfile
                  │                   ├── pipeline2_module.py
                  │                   └── main.py
                  └── common
                            ├── common_module1.py
                            └── common_module2.py
```

Every `Dockerfile` looks somewhat like:

```
FROM python:3.11-slim

WORKDIR /my_repo

# do some stuff
.
.
.

COPY . /my_repo
```

To build a new docker, using google cloud build, I'm running:

```
cd my_repo/dataflow/pipelines/pipeline1
gcloud builds submit . --tag=$IMAGE
```

My problem is that only the `pipeline1` folder contents are being copied in the `COPY . /my_repo` dockerfile command.
What modifications do I need to do to copy either the entire `dataflow` folder, or even better, the `pipeline1` directory along with the `common` directory (everything but `pipeline2`)?

In docker CLI this could be achieved by utilizing the `docker build -f` flag, however I'm not sure how to do it similarly in google cloud build.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do something similar to `-f` in Docker, there is similar alternative in Google Cloud Build as well.

You can create cloudbuild.yaml file in the same directory as the Dockerfile. If you only want to run it from my-repo, you can have config like this:

```yaml
steps:
  # Docker Build
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['build', '-t', 
           '$REGION-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/my-docker-repo/myimage', 
           '-f', 'pipelines/pipeline1/Dockerfile',
           '.']

  # Docker Push
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['push', 
           '$REGION-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/my-docker-repo/myimage']
```

Then you can invoke it from my-repo using:

```bash
gcloud builds submit . --config pipelines/pipeline1/cloudbuild.yaml
```

I've also tried it locally and it worked. :)